# Gulp Sass compiling into very long, unexpected rule set

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

When my gulp sass task runs it creates the combined file successfully, however there are a few odd rules that stick out. These rules are about 1.5 million characters long and create about a 1.1mb file each, obviously this is unacceptable. I'm not sure if it's a bug in the compiler or a bug in our code but we are combining several dozen sass files along with a bootstrap modal sass file, which seems to part of the problem.

This is an example of one of the bootstrap-modal lines creating an issue:

```
.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

And this is what it gets compiled into: [gist](https://gist.github.com/jackley/4ba7c1359f4bbc10ebc21a43760bdc47)

Now, I can remove the problematic lines from the bootstrap-modal.scss file and it compiles fine, but I'm trying to understand the root issue.

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon in the ruleset preceding this one?

Comment: what does your `gulp-sass` task look like? I use that plugin and haven't had this problem. Is there some `@mixin` that's writing out these huge selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Search for some `@extend` in your scss file. This seems to be the root of your problem, based on your generated file.

Without all project is hard to guess.